# Anylogic: How to export datasets_log to a table after simulation run?

Tags: database, export, anylogic

I am trying to export my tables to an external database in the "after simulation run" part of the simulation. I do not want to use Excel export, but need to export to an external database.

The tables that I export are created from the log-files. **This goes well for all the log-files but the datasets_log.** Meaning, I can see all the tables filled in my database, but the datasets_log table is empty. While debugging I found that the datasets_log is empty at "after simulation run", so it seems to be created after that.

Is there any other way I can export the datasets_log into a table in a way that I can get it directly into my database?

Much appreciated!